# Is it possible to order links in Plotly Sankey diagrams

Tags: plotly, sankey-diagram

[image]

I am generating this diagram with plotly.
If you look at flooding -> reporting to Triage, you can see that the highlighted route is not lined up. The transport -> reporting an issue -> triage flip at the reporting an issue node.

I am adding the links in the following order:

flooding -> reporting an issue
reporting an issue -> handled by triage

transport and highways -> reporting an issue
reporting an issue -> handled by triage

I was expecting the order of addition to influence rendering. i.e. I was expecting the green bar line from flooding -> reporting -> triage to be continuous.

Is this expectation invalid?